# How install openfaas on openshift?

Tags: openshift, faas, openfaas

I try to install OpenFaaS on OpenShift.

What I do :

- I clone "https://github.com/openfaas/faas-netes"
- I build the dockerfile. (docker build .)
- I tag and push the image on my docker hub repository

In Openshift, I deploy this image and I create a route. But the route does not run... I try kubectl in pod terminal but command does not exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: `kubectl` should be available in your host, not in your pod.

Comment: @vodasan
You probably want to use oc client instead of kubectl: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/cli_reference/get_started_cli.html

Could you share 
- the events `oc get events`, 
- the route details `oc get route <route-name> -o yaml`. 
I guess you point the route to the service, so please also share details of the service: `oc get svc <service-name> -o yaml`. 
Does the pod run? `oc get pod`.

Comment: To use OpenShift command line; You need to install oc cli and place it in your path. kubectl is used for Kubernetes and Minikube Try this for installation steps:
https://blog.openshift.com/openfaas-on-openshift/ OC CLI Download try here:
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/cli_reference/get_started_cli.html